# No custom ribbon tab (based on xml) in xlwings

Tags: xlwings

I don't see any information in xlwings documentation about adding/manipulating excel ribbon to assign control. every time we need to create a button to execute the code. Is there any way to connect custom ribbon ( based on xml) with xlwings so that code can be directly executed from ribbon?

Comment: Not right now but please open a feature request on GitHub issues